# Why do I seem to be stuck in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, random

I attempted to code a random number guessing game, mostly because I wondered if if/else could function like `goto` did on my Casio CFX-9850G.
I haven't gotten to sanitising the inputs and generating error messages (eg for setting `max` too low, entering letters instead of numbers, guessing more than max etc). My initial problem is that, while my code isn't generating an error, I can't seem to guess the number, even when I set max to 3 and try 0,1,2,3,4,5. It seems like I've created a loop, and I can't figure out where.
here's my code:

```
import random

print "GUESS MY NUMBER"

max=int(raw_input("Guess number between 1 and what?"))

randomnumber = random.randint(1,max)


def make_guess(guess):
  if guess == randomnumber:
    print "Congratulations, you guessed my number!"
  else:
    guess=raw_input("Guess again?")
    make_guess(guess)

guess=int(raw_input("What is your best guess?"))
make_guess(guess)


print "My number was" ,randomnumber
```

and it generates:

`GUESS MY NUMBER
Guess number between 1 and what? 3
What is your best guess? 0
Guess again? 1
Guess again? 2
Guess again? 3
Guess again? 4`

Now I wanted the code to loop until a correct guess, but I expected a correct guess would trigger the `if` code.

Comment: Move your function definition to the top of the code or define a main function. Don't mix up top level code and functions.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal I don't understand. Do you mean move my `def make_guess` above `print "GUESS MY NUMBER"? I tried that and it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to convert the input into an integer inside your else clause.  It actually works if you guess on the first try because you do the conversion outside the else.

Change the first line of the else:

```
guess=raw_input("Guess again?")
```

to

```
guess=int(raw_input("Guess again?"))
```

and you should be good to go.